# Problem creating alluvial diagram using ggalluvial

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, ggalluvial

I have this dataset:

```
type <- c(1, 2, NA, 1, 2, NA)
freq <- c(75, 12, 25, 69, 22, 32)
time <- c("before", "before", "before", "after", "after", "after")

df <- data.frame(type , freq, time )
```

I need to make a graph like this (with different data obviously):

[image]

I tried to follow the guide here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html

Using this code:

```
ggplot(modechoice,
       aes(x = time, stratum = type, alluvium = time,
           y = freq,
           fill = type, label = type)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(.1, .1)) +
  geom_flow() +
  geom_stratum(alpha = .5) +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", size = 3) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ggtitle("x")
```

But I get the error that my data is not recognised as an alluvial. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is hard to make a create plot with your dataset. Is it possible to add another variable?

Comment: @Quinten what would that variable be?

Comment: You should have a variable that links with your time label. Now there is nothing to combine with.

Comment: @Quinten So how should the data format be?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a fourth variable which is linked with your `time` variable, that's why I created an extra variable as an example. You can use the following code:

```
type <- c("1", "2", "NA", "1", "2", "NA")
freq <- c(75, 12, 25, 69, 22, 32)
time1 <- c("before", "before", "before", "after", "after", "after")
time2 <- c("after", "before", "after", "after", "before", "after") 


df <- data.frame(type , freq, time1, time2)

library(tidyverse)
library(ggalluvial)

ggplot(df,
       aes(y = freq, axis1 = time1, axis2 = time2)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = type), width = 1/12) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "black", color = "grey") +
  geom_label(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("time1", "time2"), expand = c(.05, .05)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
  ggtitle("x")
```

Output:

[image]

Edit after Victor Nielson comment:

```
    type <- c("1", "2", "NA", "1", "2", "NA")
freq <- c(75, 12, 25, 69, 22, 32)
time1 <- c("before", "before", "before", "before", "before", "before")
time2 <- c("after", "after", "after", "after", "after", "after") 


df <- data.frame(type , freq, time1, time2)

library(tidyverse)
library(ggalluvial)

ggplot(df,
       aes(y = freq, axis1 = time1, axis2 = time2)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = type), width = 1/12) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "black", color = "grey") +
  geom_label(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("time1", "time2"), expand = c(.05, .05)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
  ggtitle("x")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I was thinking that the first (black) column is supposed to be before and the other column is after and that the variables along these columns is the type.

Comment: @VictorNielsen, but then you will get just horizontal paths from left before to right after.

Comment: I have two times, before and after. I want to see how the number of type 1 and 2 and NA changes from the before to the after.

Comment: @VictorNielsen, I added some code with two times with before and after.

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong. There shouldn't be six, but just three. If you look at the data, there are three entries of freq (one for each type) in the before and three in the after. It looks like you put the same 6 on before and after when there are two sets of 3s.